# Ubuntu 14.10 x64 and i386

Tags: boot, system-installation, 64-bit, 32-bit, 14.10

I'm a pretty new user to Ubuntu.

I downloaded the 14.10 x64 iso for my new laptop and it installed and dual booted fine. I was super pleased with how fast it ran so I decided to install it on my 8 year old netbook (I don't plan on dual booting with this, however). At first I accidentally used the x64 version and installed it on the 32 bit netbook. It was very slow then I realized I installed the wrong version. So, I downloaded the i386 iso 14.10 yesterday, burned it to a disk, tried to install it and the computer doesn't recognize the disk as bootable so it skips it and boots from the harddrive. I looked at the files in the x64 and they are pretty much the same except the i386 is missing the "EFI" folder and some things in the boot folder. I don't know if that makes a difference. If anyone knows what I'm doing wrong with the i386 version, please reply.
Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't install the 64-bit version on a 32-bit machine. It won't boot. If you did manage to install it, then the machine is 64-bit. However, as it's 8 years old, as you say, and a netbook, it will probably be quite slow, especially depending on how much RAM it has, and what graphics chipset it uses. If it's just slow due to the RAM, you may be able to use Xubuntu on it to get a faster system, as it is a lighter weight variation of Ubuntu, with a slightly different interface.

Comment: I'll suggest Lubuntu as it is lightier than Xubuntu

Comment: Is there any way to really check for sure if it's 64-bit or 32-bit?

Comment: Yes, get the CPU model number and check the technical documentation for it. But there is no way you can run a 64-bit OS on a 32-bit CPU. It won't boot because you can't fit 64 bits into only 32 of them.

Comment: The CPU is indeed 64-bit according to intel ark. I installed 32-bit lubuntu because it only has 1GB of ram and I already had that disk. Thanks!